# Why does this Snowflake query work without requiring the LATERAL keyword?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lateral-join

I have this view in Snowflake:

```
create or replace view foo as 
select $1 as id_foo, $2 as sales
  from (values (1,100),(2,200),(3,300));
```

And this [user-defined table function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-table-functions.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_aux_table ( restriction number )
  RETURNS TABLE ( aux_id number )
  AS 'select $1 as aux_id from (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) where aux_id = restriction';
```

The following query works, and returns 3 rows:

```
 select id_foo, baz.aux_id
  from foo
 cross join table(build_aux_table(foo.id_foo)) baz;
```

However, I didn't expect the query to compile, because the UDTF-generated table with which we are joining *depends on a column from the first table*. My understanding was that this sort of intra-table dependency required a [LATERAL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html) join, like the following (which also works):

```
select id_foo, baz.aux_id
  from foo
 cross join lateral build_aux_table(foo.id_foo) baz;
```

Why does the query without LATERAL work?

Comment: Nice spot. I would expect same behaviour: [Table Functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-table.html) `"Table functions can also be applied to a set of rows using the LATERAL construct."`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda  Curiously, the [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) keyword is described as a table function, and yet it does require FLATTEN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
select id_foo, baz.aux_id
from foo
cross join table(build_aux_table(foo.id_foo)) baz;
```

is basically the same as:

```
select id_foo, baz.aux_id
from foo
,table(build_aux_table(foo.id_foo)) baz;
```

It is described in docs:

> [Calling JavaScript UDTFs in Queries](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html#calling-javascript-udtfs-in-queries)
>
> This simple example shows how to call a UDTF. This example passes literal values.
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM TABLE(js_udtf(10.0::FLOAT, 20.0::FLOAT));
> ```
>
> **This example calls a UDTF and passes it values from another table.** In this example, the UDTF named js_udtf is called once for each row in the table named tab1. **Each time that the function is called, it is passed values from columns c1 and c2 of the current row.**
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1, TABLE(js_udtf(tab1.c1, tab1.c2)) ;
> ```

---

> [Sample UDTFs - Examples with joins](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-table-functions.html#examples-with-joins)
>
> Use the UDTF in a join with another table; **note that the join column from the table is passed as an argument to the function.**
>
> ```
> select * 
> from favorite_years y join table(favorite_colors(y.year)) c;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It's not mentioned explicitly in the Snowflake manual (at least where you linked to), but it's standard behavior that the `LATERAL` keyword is optional for **functions**. Quoting the [PostgreSQL manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

> Table functions appearing in `FROM` can also be preceded by the key
> word `LATERAL`, but **for functions the key word is optional**; the
> function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by
> preceding `FROM` items in any case.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

Makes sense too, IMHO. Where would a function get its arguments, if not from other tables? Would be restricted to manual input without lateral references.

Comment: One alternative source of arguments could be side-effects, like getting the current timestamp or generating some random value (but perhaps views could work just as well there).

Comment: @danidiaz: Useful applications. But where would a *reference* point to, if not to lateral tables (table expressions) in the `FROM` clause?