# Not sure I understand the Snowflake FROM syntax using comma and table(...)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For instance, if I create two simple tables and join them through a comma or Cross Join, I see no difference

```
CREATE TABLE T1(C1A     STRING NOT NULL
               ,C1B     STRING NOT NULL
               );
           
           
CREATE TABLE T2(C2A     STRING NULL
               ,C2B     STRING NULL
               );
           
INSERT INTO T1(C1A, C1B) VALUES('1', 'One'), (2, 'Two');

INSERT INTO T2(C2A, C2B) VALUES(NULL, 'Alpha'), (2, 'Beta'), (3, 'toto');

SELECT * FROM T1, T2; -- pretty much a cross join?

SELECT * FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2;
```

I don't see the difference btween the last 2 queries

Now, how do we explain the syntax found in one of the Snowflake examples?

We create a table with a variant column and load some JSON data in it

```
CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."NESTED_INGEST_JSON" ( "RAW_NESTED_BOOK" VARIANT );
```

I don't quite understand the syntax of the query below...

```
SELECT value
    FROM NESTED_INGEST_JSON
    ,table(flatten(RAW_NESTED_BOOK:authors));
```

I understand FLATTEN() is a table function returning several rows for each row in the base table but I am still confused about the use of "," and the association table(flatten(...))

The closest explanation I found in the documentation is about the LATERAL command...

In my earlier example, I can retrieve something looking like an INNER JOIN using the comma syntax as follows

```
SELECT * 
    FROM T1
    , LATERAL ( SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE T2.C2A = T1.C1A );
```

I can also use this syntax

```
SELECT * 
    FROM T1, T2
    WHERE T2.C2A = T1.C1A;
```

Which behaves like an inner join

But I am still confused about the syntax

```
SELECT value
    FROM NESTED_INGEST_JSON
    ,table(flatten(RAW_NESTED_BOOK:authors));
```

Comment: `,` is a `CROSS JOIN`.  You should be able to use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` instead of `, LATERAL`.

Comment: Indeed! Many thanks

If you could put it as an answer, I'll vote for it!

Comment: [Why does this Snowflake query work without requiring the LATERAL keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241919/why-does-this-snowflake-query-work-without-requiring-the-lateral-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying comments to an answer for closure (I'll delete this one if Gordon comes back):

- In SQL `,` is equivalent to `CROSS JOIN`.

That's ANSI-89 vs ANSI-92. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918601/132438

(choose an explicit join if possible, if you have the choice)

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Multiple pages in the Snowflake documentation insist that the comma represents an inner join rather than a cross join, but it never worked that way for me. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral#usage-notes

Comment: Ah, but `lateral` joins are a special case

Comment: The documentation says they aren't a special case